# sql - getting text between parentheses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I have text like this:

```
San Demetrio Corone (CS)
Villanova Tulo (NU)
```

I need to get the text between parentheses, I did this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a.place, CHARINDEX('(', a.place) + 1, CHARINDEX(')', a.place, CHARINDEX('(', a.place)+ 1)  - CHARINDEX(')', a.place) - 1)
FROM tab1 a
```

but I'm getting error about lenght parameter, what's wrong in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your length input to `SUBSTRING` is off.  The length should be the difference in position between the closing and opening parentheses, offset by one less.

```
SELECT
    place,
    SUBSTRING(place,
              CHARINDEX('(', place) + 1,
              CHARINDEX(')', place) - CHARINDEX('(', place) - 1) AS abbr
FROM tab1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Yeah, i Just needed to wait some minutes, I'm doing it now